# Ruby on rails devise_token_auth gem unable to find routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I do the following steps:

## 1. Create Rails Application

```
rails new my_api_app --api
```

## 2. Add the devise_token_auth gem

```
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'omniauth'
```

## 3. Install Bundle

```
bundle install
```

## 4. Install the Gem

```
rails g devise_token_auth:install User auth
rails db:migrate
```

## 5. Set routes

```
  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for "User", at: 'auth', skip: [:omniauth_callbacks]
    end
  end
```

## 6.  Here is rails routes result

[image]

## 7. Test application on Rest Client via browser:

[image]

## 8. Here is the logs:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'new' could not be found for DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController):
  
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

## PLEASE HELP TO DETECT WHAT IS WRONG WITH CODE, ANY HINT OR HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED.

Comment: can you try changing the version of devise_token_auth to 0.1.31.beta8, https://rubygems.org/gems/devise_token_auth/versions/0.1.31.beta8

Comment: I have changed but nothing chnage, don't know why it did not catch the routses